# onRestoreInstanceState not being called after onActivityResult() is returned from a contact picker?

Tags: android

I have an activity that allows a user to pick a contact and it returns the result using onActivityResult().

When the activity is returned from the contact picker i am trying to pull some content out of a bundle in onRestoreInstanceState(). But after the onActivityResult is called the onRestore does run..

I am log.e it to check to see if it is ran and it isnt...

Here is my onRestore

```
@Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(outState);
        Log.e("SmsEditCreate", "Inside onRestore");
        mDbHelper.open();
        setRowIdFromIntent();
        populateField();
    }
```

Does onRestore not get called when return onActivityResult() is called?

If there is another way around this please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

onRestoreInstanceState is only called when your activity is being created after it was destroyed. That may happen after starting another activity, but if its not necessary, Android will keep your old activity alive as long as possible.

The activity life cycle may be of some use to you if you are looking for an appropriate time to do your work. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: Okay, So to the second part of my question. How do i get around this, when needing to pull information out of the Bundle in onResume()?

Comment: Well, I can't really answer your question specifically because you did not post what you were trying to do. I can say, though, that the instance of your Activity will be the same instance that was in use before starting the old activity. So, you can use whatever fields in your Activity class that you were trying to persist with onSaveInstanceState in your onResume(). In other words, if you set the field mRowId to be the rowId you are using, you can use mRowId directly in your onResume. In your onRestoreInstanceState, you could also set mRowId from the bundle.